# Array of unknown rank as subroutine argument

Tags: fortran

I am designing a module which works with the hdf5 Fortran library. This module contains subroutines to read and write arrays of different types and shapes to/from a file.

e.g. I wish to be able to call writeToHDF5(filepath, array) regardless of what the shape and type of array is. I realise that interfaces have to be used to achieve this with different types. I am however wondering if it is possible to have an assumed shape of the array.

e.g.

if an array was defined such as

```
integer(kind=4), dimension(*),intent(in) :: array
```

and a two dimensional array was passed this would work. Is there any way to do this without creating separate subroutines for each shape of the array?

Comment: `dimension(*)` is assumed size, not assumed shape. `integer(kind=4)` is bad, it does not portably mean 4 bytes.

Comment: What is the actual definition of ` writeToHDF5`? Are you allowed to change it at all?

Comment: There is a thing called *assumed rank* in Fortran 2015 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_15.1.0/com.ibm.xlf151.aix.doc/language_ref/assumedrankobject.html But it is useful mainly for C interop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Vladimir F says, Fortran 2015 adds "assumed-rank" - this **is** useful Fortran-Fortran (it was requested by MPI for the Fortran bindings), but when you receive such an array, you can't do much with it directly without additional complications. Several compilers support this already, but few (if any?) support the newly added SELECT RANK construct that make this a bit more useful.

You can, however, use C_LOC and C_F_POINTER to "cast" the assumed-rank dummy to a pointer to an array of whatever rank you like, so that's a possibility.

The standard (even back to Fortran 90) does give you an out here. If you write:`call writeToHDF5(filepath, array(1,1))` (assuming array is rank 2 here), the explicit interface of the called procedure can specify any rank for the dummy argument through the magic of "sequence association". There are some restrictions, though - in particular the array is not allowed to be assumed-shape or POINTER.

Comment: I might change the first occurrence of the word *useful* here to *usable* particularly since the rest of the answer explains how not-useful the feature currently is !

Comment: Very useful for generic interfaces, especially where all you care about is the block of memory.

Comment: Another useful approach is using MAP and UNION and having the same memory expressed and (N,M) and (NxM). This works on ifort with the !DEC$ extensions. You then pass the array and maybe N and M. Another handy thing with this is that if N=2 or 3, and M is very large, like perhaps data that was 'a structure'; then the 1D version vectorises without a bunch of time peel/remainder stuff happening. Another option is to RESHAPE and use (... , N, M) to sort out the shape internally from 1D back to 2D. I personally find this is easier to avoid bounds violation than just using a pointer.

Comment: I wouldn't use UNION/MAP for this (and while they are DEC extensions, they aren't !DEC$ directives.) If you are using ifort and don't mind using an extension, you can add !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: argname and then the compiler won't check ranks (or types). I think there are better ways to handle such things.

Comment: the c_loc approach handled this very well.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph - can you please provide an example? I'm only familiar with sequence association in the context of assumed-size or size-1 arrays, as described in [here](https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/advanced-array-passing-in-fortran.html). But those require passing the array size, which in `writeToHDF5()` you don't. Also I assume those techniques require an array (or array slice), ie `array(:1,:1)` and not an array element such as `array(1,1)`.

Comment: @user19087 the standard calls out the specific case of passing a single element of an array - this is then compatible with a dummy argument that is an array of any rank (as long as it isn't deferred shape or rank). The dummy argument becomes associated with the passed element and elements following it, which is sequence association. Example:
`integer :: a(5)
call sub(a(2))
...
subroutine sub (b)
integer :: b(2,2)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this comes out late, but for any future readers - the answer is actually yes.
This is a simple example of a procedure to read a single data-set of integers with any given shape. The inputs needed were read from the HDF5 using a single routine which does not require any special specification and are the same for integer, real, string and so on.
I have tested it on a "0-D" array (so size of (/1/) ), 1-D, 2-D, 3-D and 4-D arrays.
In all cases, the data was retrieved properly.
(Note: I removed some checks regarding the Errorflag, as they are not critical for the example)

```
  subroutine ReadSingleDataset_int(FileName,DataName,DataType,Data_dims,Errorflag,InputArray)
  implicit none
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: FileName,DataName
  integer(HID_T), intent(in)   :: DataType
  integer(hsize_t), dimension(:), intent(in) :: Data_dims
  logical, intent(out) :: ErrorFlag
  integer, dimension(*), intent(inout) :: InputArray

  integer :: hdferr
  integer(HID_T) :: file_id,dset_id

  ErrorFlag=.FALSE.

  IF (.NOT.HDF5_initialized) THEN
     CALL h5open_f(hdferr)
     HDF5_initialized=.TRUE.
  ENDIF

  call h5fopen_f(trim(FileName),H5F_ACC_RDONLY_F, file_id, hdferr)
  call h5dopen_f(file_id,trim(DataName),dset_id,hdferr)

  call h5dread_f(dset_id,DataType,InputArray,Data_dims,hdferr)

  call h5dclose_f(dset_id,hdferr)
  call h5fclose_f(file_id,hdferr)

  end subroutine ReadSingleDataset_int
```

My main interest in this now is - would it be possible to replace the type/class specific (integer/real/etc') with a generic one on the lines of:

```
class(*), dimension(*), intent(inout) :: InputArray
```

As I have several routines like that (for int, real, string) which only vary in that specification of the input type/class. If that limitation could be alleviated as well, that will be even more elegant.
(Just to point out the issue - the `h5dread_f` does not accept the buffer argument, `InputArray` in my case, to be unlimited polymorphic)