# Write assumed rank entity to file

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

I am trying to write out an assumed rank array to a file:

```
    subroutine write_dbl_gen(filename, array)
        Implicit None
        character(len=*), intent(in)     :: filename
        real(8), intent(in)              :: array(..)

        open(unit=p_un, file=filename, form="unformatted",&
             access="stream")
        write (p_un) array
        close(unit=p_un)
    end subroutine write_dbl_gen
```

ifort then complains:

```
(base) > $ make                                                                                                                                                                                     [±master ●]
[ 25%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/npy.x.dir/src/npy.F90.o
/Users/redies/NPY-for-Fortran/src/npy.F90(835): error #8842: An I/O list item must not be an assumed rank object.   [ARRAY]
        write (p_un) array
---------------------^
compilation aborted for /Users/redies/NPY-for-Fortran/src/npy.F90 (code 1)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/npy.x.dir/src/npy.F90.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/npy.x.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I write an assumed rank array to a file? I tried reshaping it, but the "reshape" function won't take assumed rank arrays. I tried a similar thing using "transfer" but it has the same problem.

Comment: I don't think you can do that at all. Unless you use `select rank` but than you might not use assumed rank in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumed-rank entities are very limited in where they can appear.  The particular constraint (Fortran 2018, C837) says:

> An assumed-rank variable name shall not appear in a designator or expression except as an actual argument that corresponds to a dummy argument that is assumed-rank, the argument of the function C_LOC or C_SIZEOF from the intrinsic module ISO_C_BINDING (18.2), the first dummy argument of an intrinsic inquiry function, or the selector of a SELECT RANK statement.

ifort is right to complain about the use in the subroutine of the question.

As Vladimir F comments, one can use a SELECT RANK construct to make a non-assumed-rank entity which can be then used in (potentially) multiple write statements (one for each rank).

However, as noted in [an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39773295/3157076), it's possible to "cast" some assumed-rank entities to another of known rank which can then be used in the write statement:

```
   real(8), pointer :: output_array(:)
   call c_f_pointer(c_loc(array), output_array, [size(array)])
   write (p_un) output_array
```

Because of the use of `c_loc` from `iso_c_binding` here `array` should have the `target` attribute added.

---

In my example above, `size` is an intrinsic inquiry function which is why `size(array)` is allowed.  From the question, `reshape` and `transfer` are instead *transformational* functions, explaining why they do not accept the assumed-rank array as an argument.